# Trello API: How can I modify a checklist?

Tags: trello

I have a Trello card and it has a checklist with several items.  I am looking for a way to update the items' state, with either complete or incomplete. Basically the equivalent of if you were to click on it in the UI.

From the what I can see in the docs, there is no call that does a PUT or POST for a checkItem.  The closest I see is the method below, but that would seem to allow you to just add a checkItem to the list.

```
POST /1/checklists/[idChecklist]/checkItems
```

Answer (score 1):

For various embarrassing legacy reasons, it has to be done through the `/1/card/checklist/...` routes. The documentation for that is here:

https://trello.com/docs/api/card/index.html#put-1-cards-card-id-or-shortlink-checklist-idchecklist-checkitem-idcheckitem-name